# In Xcode 11, what is the button below the Live Preview button?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, ios13

In Xcode 11, there are two buttons next to the device preview. The one on the top we all know is the Live Preview. However the one on the bottom does not seem to be doing anything. Why would Apple leave a completely useless button there? Am I missing out some awesome functionality?

The button icon looks like it could be related to constraints... but I don't know.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This button lets you to instantly run the app on an **attached device** so you can see the live changes directly on your device instead of Xcode's canvas preview.

Note that you need iOS 13 installed on your device to be able to use this capability.

Comment: You also seem to need Catalina installed on the host (as for on host previews), which is a bit of a shame. If this isn't the case, please let me know!